# Is this usage of “entirety” correct?

Tags: word-usage

> The region remained volatile for the entirety of the twenty-five years it was under occupation.

Also, is the sentence well-structured/grammatically correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELL. Can you tell us why you're unsure about this sentence? It would help us answer better.